# How do I find System32 directory in Electron?

Tags: windows, electron

I understand one should not just assume c:\windows\system32 is where system32 will be located but that there's a way to query Windows for it's location. My goal is to find the directory where I can copy a .scr (screensaver) to so that Windows finds it.

How do I do that? Specifically, how do I do that from an Electron app?

Comment: And you need to know because? 64-bit Windows has two system32 directories.

Comment: @Anders to install a screensaver.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 system provided environment variables you can use. I have Windows 10

```
SystemRoot=C:\WINDOWS and
windir=C:\WINDOWS
```

So System32 would be

```
%SystemRoot%\System32 or
%windir%\System32
```

Comment: This fails to account for running in the WoW64 emulation layer.

Comment: @IInspectable op specifically asked where is System32. SysWOW64 is also in %windir%. But maybe I don't understand your point.

Comment: With [file system redirection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187.aspx) in place, asking for *System32* is ambiguous. It depends on what the OP is trying to do with that information, whether or not they need the redirected name, or the underlying file system path.

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to install a screensaver.